# BIOS update mistake

Tags: bios, lenovo-laptop

I was trying to enable Virtualization in BIOS settings and by mistake, I may have set the BIOS to default. Now the BIOS version is showing 'LENOVO JBET54WW (1.19), 11/6/2015'. After this update I believe, laptop is behaving weird. My battery is draining when the lid is closed overnight and Laptop is getting heated up. (Power Options are set correctly - Lid Closed - Sleep) I know battery is good and it is a new one. I do not face this issue while I am working on battery. Question:

How do I know what was my previous version of BIOS ?
Is there a way I can revert back and how.
Thanks -VJ

Comment: Setting BIOS to default is normally not a problem. I assume you have a Lenovo machine. Look on the Lenovo support site for that machine and see what is the current name and level of BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the BIOS's settings won't revert it to a previous version. You would have to go through the BIOS and take a look at the settings related to power management.